# Why I obtain this FileNotFoundException when I try to use log4j to write into a file?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, filenotfoundexception

I am absolutly new using **log4j** and I have the following problem.

I am trying to print the logging line into a file named **log.out**.

So I create the following **log4j.properties** configuration file:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

The problem is that, when I perform my application and when it incurs in a logging operation, something like this:

```
logger.debug("INTO main()");
```

I obtain the following exception into the console (the error message related to the **log.out** file is **access denied** (in italian Accesso negato):

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \log.out (Accesso negato)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:289)
        at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:163)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:2
56)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.j
ava:132)
        at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.j
ava:96)
        at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigura
tor.java:654)
```

and don't write nothing into my **log.out** file (that I have created manually). This **log.out** file is at the same level of the performed jar file that represent my application.

Why? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Tnx

Comment: log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out is ${log}  variable set ?

Comment: mmm no. I thought that automatically referers to the position of my application. Exist a way to say to log4j that the file have been created into the folder that contains the executed jar?

Comment: just hardcode some folder location in log4 property file. where you know your user has access . Or just write log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.out  the file will be created in the default directory of the user.

Comment: tutorial source : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think $log is empty and it's trying to create a file on root and you are running program as a normal user.
give it a check.

Comment: On the root of what? I want that the log file is created at the same level of the performed jar (my application)

Comment: Can you try it using only this
log4j.appender.FILE.File=log.out

it should solve permission related issue.

Comment: now you  also might wanna check your $log variable. It seems it's empty.

Answer (score 5):

For logging when using properties file following config should work. For the **tomcat** application server, please use `${catalina.base}` to get the tomcat base directory.

```
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${catalina.base}/logs/debug.log
```

For XML config the syntax might be like the following

```
<param name="file" value="${catalina.base}/logs/debug.log"/>
```

If you are using Tomcat as your application server, I hope it will work.